# How can I send saved library videos through Snapchat?

Tags: video, ios, iphone

For pictures I can see the share option to send it through snapchat, but I can't seem to find it for videos.

I want to be able to record a video using the phones default camera app and then send it to a friend on Snapchat. Since the video is likely to be longer than 10 seconds if it would send multiple videos of 10 seconds each that would be ideal.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Snapchat now has the desired capability of sending videos from the camera roll in 10 second chunks.

Head to **Memories** by clicking the circle (now “cards” in 2018) on the bottom center of the screen (or swiping up) on the camera screen and then go to camera roll section on top and long press the video you want and press the blue arrow to share it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't send videos through Snapchat. In the photos app, if you select a photo a share button will pop up(box with arrow). It will give you a myriad of options to send your photo/video. If you've selected a photo, it gives you a Snapchat option. If you select a video, there is no Snapchat. Seems like Snapchat forces you to use their camera for videos.

Comment: I know of at least one app that can do it, unfortunately it's not free, need to either pay or do tasks to send a video

Comment: Yeah, there's probably some apps out there, but with only official apps it isn't possible.